# NHibernate:Associate existing object with new object?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Clearly I am searching on the wrong keywords.

I have objects `Vendor` and `Invoice` in an NHibernate project like so:

```
public class Vendor
{
    public string theName { get; set; }
}

public class Invoice
{
    public Vendor theVendor { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

I have a UnitOfWork style interface with NH `VendorRepository` and `InvoiceRepository` repositories... these seem to be working.

I can create a Vendor no sweat, sorta like this:

```
public void CreateVendor(string name)
{
    using (var u = new UnitOfWork())
    {
        var v = new Vendor();
        v.theName = name;
        u.Vendors.Add(v);
        u.Save();
    }
}
```

Creating the `Invoice` object, however, requires a reference to `Vendor`.  I thought this would be as simple as:

```
public void CreateInvoice(decimal theAmount, string vendorName)
{
    using (var u = new UnitOfWork())
    {
        var i = new Invoice();
        i.Amount = theAmount;
        var v = u.Vendors.GetByName(vendorName);
        i.theVendor = v;
        u.Invoices.Add(i);
        u.Save();
    }
}
```

However, this does not appear to be the case.  Do I need to do some special NHibernate voodoo for this?  I'd prefer to keep the NHibernate behind the UnitOfWork interface, but I'd like to cleanly associate the objects with minimal code or confusion.

**UPDATE** Per request:
Mapping file (extra stuff removed) for Vendor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="DataModel"
                   namespace="DataModel">
    <class name="Vendor" table="Vendors">
        <id name="APVendorId">
            <generator class="guid" />
        </id>
        <property name="theName" index="ixVendorName" length="100" not-null="true" column="VendorName" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and for Invoice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                    assembly="C3.DataModel"
                    namespace="C3.DataModel">
    <class name="Invoice" table="Invoices">
        <id name="InvoiceId">
            <generator class="guid" />
        </id>
        <one-to-one name="Vendor" class="Vendor" constrained="true" cascade="none" fetch="join" />
        <property name="theAmount" column="InvoiceAmount" not-null="true" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The repository code resembles this:

```
///<summary>
///Auto-generated NHibernate repository for the domain POCO object <strong>APInvoice</strong>
///</summary>
public partial class NHInvoiceRepository : IInvoiceRepository
{
    internal ISession _Session;
    internal ITransaction _Transaction;
    private bool _IndependentSession;

    ///<summary>
    ///Adds a Invoice object to the NHibernate repository.
    ///</summary>
    public void Add(Invoice invoice)
    {
        _Session.Save(invoice);
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Instantiates the repository in standalone (no associated UnitOfWork) mode.  This should usually be avoided.
    ///</summary>
    internal NHInvoiceRepository()
    {
        _Session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession();
        _Transaction = _Session.BeginTransaction();
        _IndependentSession = true;
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Instantiates the repository as a part of a UnitOfWork pattern.
    ///</summary>
    public NHInvoiceRepository(ISession session, ITransaction transaction)
    {
        _Session = session;
        _Transaction = transaction;
        _IndependentSession = false;
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Instantiates the repository as a part of a UnitOfWork pattern.
    ///</summary>
    public NHInvoiceRepository(ISession session)
    {
        _Session = session;
        _Transaction = _Session.BeginTransaction();
        _IndependentSession = false;
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Implements the IDisposable interface.
    ///</summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _Transaction.Dispose();
        _Session.Dispose();
        return;
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Commits the changes in the repository in standalone (no associated UnitOfWork) mode.
    ///</summary>
    public void Save()
    {
        if (_IndependentSession)
        {
            _Transaction.Commit();
            _Transaction = _Session.BeginTransaction();
        }
    }

}
```

The UnitOfWork code looks like this:

```
///<summary>
///UnitOfWork Interface.  The primary data interface between the data model and the persistence layer.
///</summary>
public partial class NHUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private ISession _Session;
    private ITransaction _Transaction;
    public IVendorRepository Vendors { get; private set; }
    public IInvoiceRepository Invoices { get; private set; }

    public void Save()
    {
        Vendors.Save();
        Invoices.Save();
        _Transaction.Commit();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Vendors.Dispose();
        Invoices.Dispose();
        _Transaction.Dispose();
        _Session.Dispose();
    }

    public NHUnitOfWork()
    {
        _Session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession();
        _Transaction = _Session.BeginTransaction();
        Vendors = new NHVendorRepository(_Session);
        Invoices = new NHInvoiceRepository(_Session);
    }
}
```

The error message I am getting is:

```
NHibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value
```

I did try changing the one to one to a many-to-one in the mappings, with no different results.

**UPDATE** on the second recompile, (and rebuilding the db schema) this change worked.

Comment: Why not have the method require a vendor instance instead? That would make more sense to me `public void CreateInvoice(decimal theAmount, Vendor vendor);`

Comment: I think the problem is with your mappings, can you post the mappings of your both classes??

Comment: It should work fine with NHibernate. How do `Vendors.Add()` and `UnitOfWork.Save()` work?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: I'd like to avoid that if I can... most of the code is auto-generated through reflection, and while I can figure out relationships like that if I have to, I'd rather not dive that deep into my text templates if I don't have to.

Comment: @Jupaol, I have added the mappings.  Please forgive typos, I stripped out a lot of other properties for the sake of brevity.

Comment: @ivowiblo, I have added the repository code and the UnitOfWork code.  Extra stuff was removed for brevity's sake.

Comment: When you moved to many-to-one you received the same error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always have troubles with `<one-to-one>` mappings. I suggest to move to `<many-to-one unique="true">`

Comment: I think (think) that NHibernate expect both objects to have the same id when they are related with one-to-one. I guess <one-to-one> was not defined for 1 to 0..1 as you need.

Comment: Based on the error you are having, I'm pretty sure that's the problem. Check this link: http://ayende.com/blog/3960/nhibernate-mapping-one-to-one

Comment: Sorry, the tags got removed :)

Comment: Hmm... I recompiled with this and it didn't work, but I did it again and it worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with this line

```
<one-to-one name="Vendor" class="Vendor" constrained="true" cascade="none" fetch="join" />
```

Try replace it with

```
<many-to-one name="Vendor" unique="true" cascade="all" fetch="join" />
```

Comment: easy with cascade="all". But I think a "save-update" will be enough

Comment: Mmmhhh now that I think it better, I don't believe it's a cascade issue. So, the cascade="all" shouldn't be there

Comment: Did u try? that's the way most Mapping generators map this kind of relation

Comment: Do you know what that means? I think he put cascade="none" for a reason.

Comment: yes, I want nothing cascading... no data should be deleted through this interface, (that's important) so I make it as difficult as possible to do so, especially when one deletion could end up wiping out a bunch of stuff.